# why arrayList.sort() doestnt work with me?

Tags: c#

```
ArrayList x = new ArrayList();
var sevenItems = new byte[] { 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20 };
var sevenItems2 = new byte[] { 0x10, 0x00, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20,0x20 };
x.Add(sevenItems);
x.Add(sevenItems2);
x.sort(); //doesnt work
```

The output is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll Failed to compare two elements in the array.

May i know why it doesnt work? Is there any way to sort list or byte arrays?

Comment: what type of mix is this? `.sort` is java, did you meant `Sort`? Also, don't spam tags, if this is c# mark it as c# only.

Comment: i can accept answer on java code

Comment: anyway i am sorry  c# is good

Comment: You are adding two byte arrays in your arraylist... what is the criterion for comparing them since sort is performed on a comparison basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding two byte arrays in your `ArrayList` and trying to sort them. Since sorting is performed on a comparison basis... at runtime your application complains about a missing criterion for defining a priority between the two arrays.

```
public class BytesComparer : IComparer
{
    Int32 IComparer.Compare(Object x, Object y)
    {
        Byte[] left = (Byte[])x;
        Int32 val1 = BitConverter.ToInt32(left.Take(4).ToArray(), 0);

        Byte[] right = (Byte[])y;
        Int32 val2 = BitConverter.ToInt32(right.Take(4).ToArray(), 0);

        return val1.CompareTo(val2);
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ArrayList x = new ArrayList();
    Byte[] sevenItems1 = new Byte[] { 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20 };
    Byte[] sevenItems2 = new Byte[] { 0x10, 0x00, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20,0x20 };

    x.Add(sevenItems1);
    x.Add(sevenItems2); 
    x.Sort(new BytesComparer());
}
```